# repeat bash history expansion substitution for all the matches

Tags: bash, command-history

`:&` repeats bash history expansion substitution. For example:

```
$ echo 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
$ ^1^9
echo 9 1 1 1 1
9 1 1 1 1
$ echo 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
$ ^1^9^:&
echo 9 9 1 1 1
9 9 1 1 1
$ echo 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
$ ^1^9^:&:&:&:&
echo 9 9 9 9 9
9 9 9 9 9
$
```

As seen above, one needs to type `:&` for each repetition. Is there a way to repeat substitution for all the matches automatically? I mean something like:

```
$ echo 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
$ ^1^9^:*
echo 9 9 9 9 9
9 9 9 9 9
$
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [event designators](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Event-Designators) instead:

```
$ echo 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
$ !!:gs/1/9/
echo 9 9 9 9 9
9 9 9 9 9
```

`!!` is a [word designator](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Word-Designators) which expands to the previous command run. `s` and `g` are [modifiers](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Modifiers):

> After the optional word designator, you can add a sequence of one or more of the following modifiers, each preceded by a ‘:’.
>
> s/old/new/
>
> Substitute new for the first occurrence of old in the event line. [...]
>
> g/a
>
> Cause changes to be applied over the entire event line. Used in conjunction with ‘s’, as in `gs/old/new/`, or with ‘&’.

So, `!!:gs/1/9/` means "run the previous command, replacing all 1s with 9s".